# How can I disable gzip inside php code on HHVM? (eg setting content-encoding header)

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, gzip, hhvm

I'm converting php code to hhvm. One page in particular sometimes needs to flush() a status-message to the browser before sending some emails and a few other slow tasks and then updating the status message.

Before hhvm (using php-fpm and nginx) I used:

```
header('Content-Encoding: none;');

echo "About to send emails...";
if (ob_get_level() > 0) { ob_end_flush(); }
flush();

// Emails sent here

echo "Emails sent.";
```

So the content-encoding stops gzip being used, then the flush sends the first message, then the second message is sent when the page ends.

Using HHVM (and nginx), setting the Content-encoding header works (it shows up in the browser), but either hhvm or nginx is ignoring it and sending the page as gzipped content, so the browser interprets the content-encoding=none with binary data.

How can I disable gzip inside php code on HHVM?

(I know I could turn it off in the config files, but I want it kept on for nearly every page load except a few that will run slower.)

Comment: it is best to keep the content plaintext, and let nginx take care of gzipping. you could create a custom rule for nginx (for a specific url pattern) to not gzip the output. How does this sound?

Comment: @Sina Thanks, to clarify: The php code isn't doing a gzip, only in nginx, but it shouldn't gzip in this case as it's being sent in 2 parts. The custom rule would be the last resort (it would mean re-structuring a lot of code, which would be annoying seeing as it had been working under our old setup.)

Comment: I think this is probably an hhvm bug, I've posted an issue here: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2641

Comment: having exactly same issue. any solution yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338641/nginx-php-hhvm-produce-duplicate-content-encoding-header

Comment: I gave up on it at the time, and haven't got back to trying HHVM since. Now that php7 is out and runs at a similar speed we're just going to stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

While my suggestion would be to have different nginx location paths with different gzip configuration, here's a better alternative solution to achieve what you want to happen.

### Better Solution:

It is often referred to as bad practice to keep a connection open (and the browser loading bar spinning) while you're doing work in the background.

Since PHP 5.3.3 there is a method [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)  which flushes the data and closes the connection, while it continues to work in the background.

Now, [this is unfortunately not supported yet on HHVM](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1230). However, there is an alternative way of doing this.

## HHVM alternative:

You can use `register_postsend_function('function_name');` instead. This closes the connection, and the given function will be executed in the background.

### Here is an example:

```php
<?php

echo "and ...";

register_postsend_function(function() {
  echo "... you should not be seeing this";
  sleep("10"); // do a lot of work
});

die();
```

Comment: Thanks @Sina, that will be a good option for some people. But in my case the second status message is more important than the first (and the background tasks usually only take 2-3 seconds.) So in my case it'd be better to leave the connection open and remove the first status message than to lose the second.